# SOCKS5 Proxy for Chromium

Tags: proxy, chrome

I am trying to use my SOCKS5 proxy with username and password authentication in Google Chromium.

I have tried almost every possible proxy switcher addon available in the chrome extensions store. All of them have neglected to add support for authentication, except for "Proxy Helper", which does not work. I am confident my proxy server is configured correctly, as it works in other applications.

The proxy settings button in the Chromium settings tab is "grayed out"/disabled, however this would only load the DE-specific proxy settings panel. I do not wish to use this proxy system wide, so this is not an option anyway.

I have determined that it is possible to specify a proxy for chromium using command-line flags. The documentation [on the Chromium site](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy) has no mention of username/password authentication at all.

So I feel as if I have exhausted all possible options. Who would have thought such a seemingly-simple configuration would be so difficult.

If anyone knows if a simple "per-application" proxy configuration tool exists, similar to "Proxifier" on Windows, please let me know. I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng). It lacks command-line options for setting proxy, but you can have as many config files as you need. It might be present in your package manager as proxychains4.

Alternatively you could use redsocks or tun2socks with iptables if per-user rules are sufficient.

Comment: Should've checked this quirk before writing the answer, but here I am. Anyways, proxychains can't intercept forkers. Which Chrome inherently is. However it will still work with single-process browsers and other such software.

Answer (score 0):

**[Proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound)** can do the job

It support upstream socks5